# Get last 2 characters of a string?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

Say I have a string:

```
NSString *state = @"California, CA";
```

Can someone please tell me how to extract the last two characters from this string (`@"CA"` in this example).

Answer (score 156, accepted):

```
NSString *code = [state substringFromIndex: [state length] - 2];
```

should do it

Comment: You can also do just state.length instead of [state length] if you prefer. In the end, it's just style, though. (Also this may not be true in older iOS versions)

Comment: @LarrikJ: The dot property notation is a feature of Objective-C 2.0. It generates the same code as explicitly sending an accessor message.

Answer (score 1):

Just simply add this extension and use it for String types:

```
extension String { 
    var last2: String {
        String(self.suffix(2))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4:**

```
let code = (state as? NSString)?.substring(from: state.characters.count - 2)
```