# Extracting from the right of a string in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, text-extraction

This seems to be what I'm looking for but in reverse. I would like the `string` to extract from the right not from the left. 
The example extracting from the left is given:

```
NSString *source = @"0123456789";
NSString *firstFour = [source substringToIndex:4];

Output: "0123"
```

I'm looking for a version of the below that works from the right (what is below doesn't work)

```
NSString *source = @"0123456789";
NSString *lastFour = [source substringToIndex:-4];

Output: "6789"
```

the `[source substringFromIndex:6];` won't work because sometimes I will get an answer that is 000123456789 or 456789 or 6789. In all cases I just need the last 4 characters from the string so that I can convert it to a number.

there must be a better way than a bunch of if else statements?

Comment: `[ source substringFromIndex:source.length - 4 ]`

Comment: Very similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483223/objective-c-get-last-2-characters-of-a-string).

Answer (score 3):

As you are not sure, about the length of the string, so you must check it before extracting like this:

```
NSString *source = @"0123456789";
NSNumber *number;
if (source.length>=4) {
    NSString *lastFour=[source substringFromIndex:source.length-4];
    number=@([lastFour integerValue]); //and save it in a number, it can be int or NSInteger as per your need
}
NSLog(@"%@",number);
```

Also if you want a quick method that you need to call several times, create a category :

```
@implementation NSString (SubstringFromRight)
-(NSString *)substringFromRight:(NSUInteger)from{
    if (self.length<from) {
        return nil;
    }        
    return [self substringFromIndex:self.length-from];
}
@end
```

And use it as :`NSLog(@"%@",[source1 substringFromRight:4]);`

Comment: +1, Complete answer with exception checking.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *source = @"0123456789";
NSString *newString = [source substringFromIndex:[source length] - 4];

NSLog(@"%@",newString);
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
NSString *lastFour = [source substringToIndex:-4];
```

with

```
NSString *lastFour = [source substringFromIndex:[source length] - 4];
```

which returns you the last 4 characters of your original string `string` in `lastFour string`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to get last 4 characters from your string.

```
NSString *last4Characters = [source substringFromIndex:(source.length - 4)];
NSLog(@"Last 4 Characters:%@",last4Characters);
last4Characters=nil;
```

Please let me know if any issue.